# Open set Proof in the Real-Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ is an open interval on the real line and $B$ is a closed subinterval of $A$, show that $A - B$ is open.

**PROOF**

Let $A=(a,b)$ and $B=[c,d]$ be such that $a<c<d<b$ this way we have to $A-B=(a,c)\cup(d,b)$ and since $(a,c)$ and $(d,b)$ are open sets, and also the union of open sets is open so $A-B$ is open.

This is my test idea but my question is if there is a way to prove it without using the fact of the union of open sets.

Comment: It is very much an axiomatic property of open sets that they are closed under union, so I think that is a fine proof.

Comment: Isn't there a way to prove this without using the property of open sets?

Comment: What other property would you use?

Comment: Are you trying to show $A \setminus B = \{x \in A : x\not\in B\}$ is open or are you trying to show $A - B = \{a - b : a \in A, b \in B\}$ is open?  Your proof makes me think it's the former, but the notation often conflicts in real analysis.

Comment: I want show whth this definition $A∖B={x∈A:x∉B}$

Comment: What you said makes no sense. You need to show something is open. What definition of open are you using?

Answer (score 1):

We can show that every point of $A-B$ is an intriour point as follows:
For every $x \in A-B$

$ (x-r,x+r) \subset A-B$

where $2r=\min \{x-a,x-c,x-d,x-b\}$